# Excel + TSQL (macros to highlight cells on a condition)

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel, vba

I work with SQL Server 2012 database.

every morning I get a new table with results of calculation. Format is

**productID - countryID - 2001 - 2002 - 2003**

I have 2000 products, each in 200 countries. About 400000 rows.

Also I have table with the same format from previous calculation.

My task is to compare old and new results and create an output Excel file with format:

**Calculation - productID - countryID - 2001 - 2002 - 2003**

old          - 1         -  CA       - 0.02 - 0.89  - 5.3

new         - 1         -  CA       - 0.03 - 0.90  - 5.3

So I group by products and countries and compare values in each year.

My problem is that i need to highlight those cells where result is different for more that 2%.

Do anybody know how to do the trick??

thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry, wrote not very correctly.

my task is to automatize this process. data's differences will be checked by another department. and i am trying to implement an automatization of process: 

database -> excel file -> macro for comparison and formating excel file

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each row is preceded by the old, you would need to select the new rows, and compare with the result directly above them. Easiest way to do that is to add a filter, filter the new, select the results, add the conditional formatting, and then unfilter the results.

```
'Select everything and add a filter
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="New"
'Select the newly filtered results
Cells.Select
'Apply a conditional format (substitute B2 for the first filtered cell, and B1 for the cell above it)
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=IF(B2>(B1*1.2),TRUE,FALSE)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
     .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
     .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
     .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
'Remove the filter
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
```

Create a new Macro, and paste the above code into it and it should work.

Comment: but is it possible to write a stored procedure which will export data from database into excel file and create a "job" which will run a macro for comparing-formating?

this idea is because changes in data should be checked by another department and i cant every day compare are highlight differences with hands :) is my idea at least possible?

Comment: You should be able to setup the Excel file to Query the data from the database -No stored procedure involved. Then, run the macro to setup the conditional formatting. (You don't need the macro, but I've found that Excel sometimes forgets formatting upon data refresh, even when it is set to remember the format.)

What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: done a bit easier  
`Sub RunCheck()

Dim eilute As Integer
   
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    eilute = Selection.Cells.Row
    
    For e = 2 To eilute
    
       For s = 8 To 72
         If Cells(e, s) <> Cells(e + 1, s) Then
         Cells(e, s).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 25)
         Cells(e + 1, s).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 25)
         End If
         Next s
         e = e + 1
         Next e
    
End Sub `

Comment: You're only checking to see if the values are the same. In the original post you needed to see if there was a difference over greater than a specified value. (Although in my example I mis-typed the value and put in 20% instead of 2%)

Comment: oh :)) sorry! wrote old code! yes you are right it should be:

        If Cells(e + 1, s) <> 0 Then
            If 100 * (Abs(1 - Cells(e, s) / Cells(e + 1, s))) > 2 Then ....

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with an Excel formula :

```
A           B       C

old         0.5 
new         1       Alert !
old         0.9 
new         0.91    
old         0.1 
new         0.15    Alert !

=IF(A2="new";IF(B2-B1>0.02;"Alert !";"");"")
```

To highlight cells, you can use conditional formatting with this formula (from the menu Format)

Comment: how to compare in excel i know :) but idea is to create auto comparing program

Answer (score 0):

I would go the pivot table route. It is dynamic. Easily expandable if new information is added. And not reliant on your data being in the exact order you need it is. It can also contain conditional formatting that will expand as your data does.

Answer (score 0):

Sub RunCheck()

Dim eilute As Integer

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select

eilute = Selection.Cells.Row

For e = 2 To eilute

   For s = 8 To 72
     If Cells(e, s) <> Cells(e + 1, s) Then
     Cells(e, s).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 25)
     Cells(e + 1, s).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 25)
     End If
     Next s
     e = e + 1
     Next e
```

End Sub